# Slider Revolution cannot change text/button color

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have been working on this matter for a few weeks, and have not been able to determine why the slider revolution plugin will not allow the text and button colors to be changed. When I try to change the color in the slider plugin, nothing happens. There is no custom css/jquery in the plugin editor itself to override the color. I have also checked the theme code, line by line to see if something is conflicting. Using the chrome developer tools I can see the color code, but I cannot tell where it is pulling the data from.

https://houstonalumni.com/
(the slider in question is at the very top of the page id #rev_slider_7_1_forcefullwidth)

Comment: Create a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

You must override a hard-coded background value in the `style` attribute using the `!important` keyword

```
.rs-layer.rev-btn {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
}
```

If you don't know how to add custom CSS styles to a Wordpress page:

https://wordpress.com/support/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: thanks for replying, is there a way to stop it from overriding so that others are able to change the colors using the plugin only?

Comment: thanks, I know how to add custom css to a wordpress page. The issue is that other non-coders will be making changes to the slides and they need to be able to change the colors from the plugin.

Comment: I think all generated style is from the slide editor. Custom slides should have options to modify button properties, like in this example https://www.screencast.com/t/uyj3MF5vfNo

Comment: we do have the options to modify properties, however this is what happens when we try to modify the property: 
<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UBzstlMJcu4e2924D8NwuYqt0q-fGuyr/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: Have you tried modifying the background color property? https://imgur.com/a/svw8jJ6 
It's not clear if the text color changed, because there is no text inside the container.

Comment: Hi yes, I tried modifying the background-color property, my apologies as there was text in there however it is not visible because somehow the text color property is being overridden to white. The text says "new layer"

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OY1rVTnLT3z5rXbMO5DXVv_pLU5Z7d9p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like something else is overriding backgrounds and colors (even in the editor), I think it's not supposed to see the color selector button with white background. maybe an additional plugin,  custom CSS already changing styles. Have you tried saving changes even if it does not appear changed in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

just add properly data-color in

```
<rs-layer
                                            id="slider-7-slide-14-layer-4" 
                                            data-type="text"
                                            data-text="w:normal;s:20,20,17,15;l:30,30,30,25;fw:300;"
                                            data-dim="w:480px,480px,auto,auto;"
                                            data-rsp_o="off"
                      data-rsp_bd="off"
                      data-color="#078297"
                                            data-margin="t:50,50,20,20;"
                                            data-frame_0="y:50;"
                                            data-frame_1="st:200;sp:1000;sR:200;"
                                            data-frame_999="st:w;sR:7800;"
                                            style="z-index:5;font-family:Roboto; "
                                        >Rationalisez l'ensemble de votre flux de travail et revenez à ce qui compte le plus.
                                        </rs-layer>
```